# Android HttpConection vs Self-Signed SSL

Tags: ssl, android, java, https

Привет Хешкодеры, у меня загвоздка. Я начал изучать java связи с необходимостью написать приложение клиент для одной задачи. Все вроде хорошо идет, но тут оказалось что протокол, через который мне придется работать HTTPS, а сервер имеет самоподписанный сертификат. Покопавшись в гугле, смог откопать вот [эту](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post3429981.html) статейку. Там конечно еще что-то про апач авторизацию, но меня она не колышет. В общем попробовал я пере опипастить код, вышло гдето вот так

```
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                //publishProgress("getAcceptedIssuers");
                Log.i(lTAG,"X509Certificate: getAcceptedIssuers");
                return null;
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                Log.i(lTAG,"checkServerTrusted: Сведения о сертификате : " + chain[0].getIssuerX500Principal().getName() + "\n Тип авторизации : " + authType);
                //publishProgress("Сведения о сертификате : " + chain[0].getIssuerX500Principal().getName() + "\n Тип авторизации : " + authType);
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                //publishProgress("checkClientTrusted : " + authType);
                Log.i(lTAG,"checkClientTrusted: checkClientTrusted : " + authType);
            }
        } };
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: URL init");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: URL openConnection");
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: conn set params");
        ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: conn setSSLSocketFactory");
        ((HttpsURLConnection) conn).setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        Log.i(lTAG, "downloadUrl: conn setHostnameVerifier");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        Log.i(lTAG, "downloadUrl: conn setDoInput");
        // Start the query
        try {
            conn.connect();
            Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: conn open connect");
        }catch (Exception e){Log.i(lTAG,"downloadUrl: conn open connect eror:\n"+e.getMessage());}*/

        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

но в результате имею информацию что conn.connect(); не отрабатывает(( исключение не могу придумать какое надо подставить чтобы отработало, и вывело что-то вместо null

Answer (score 1):

В общем кому этот вопрос интересен, выше приведенный код рабочий, и способен обойти само подписанный сертификат. У меня проблема оказывается была в том что класс в котором я пилил работу с вебом, надо было сделать как оболочку AsyncTask<Type, Type, Type>.